# Import Specific JARs in Nexus Repository manager

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, nexus

Im New to Nexus repository manager i managed to Download Repos to maven
from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ ,and i have some other specific JARs in local ,Anyone knows how to import them to nexus so Maven could download both , from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ & the specific ones.

Comment: Configure your local build tool (suppose you use Maven) to use your repository manager and build your applications. If it's correctly configured the download from central (repo1.maven.org..) will be done automatically without manual interference... second to upload an artifact into Nexus you have to take a look into the documentation of Nexus (I don't know if you are using OSS/commerical version or Nexus2/Nexus3?)...

Comment: Thanks for replying! im using Nexus OSS version 3.3